# How to filter specific frequencies from an Audio file in C

Tags: c, audio

After searching on various search engines, and also here, there is very little information applicable to my situation.
Basically I want to make a program in C that does the following:

1. Open an Audio File (flac Mp3 and wav, to represent a bit of variety)
2. Filter and cut out a specific set of frequencies (for Example 4000-5200hz, the frequencies should be entered upon inquiry)
3. Save the new file (without the filtered frequencies) in the same format as the input file.

Things that would be of interest to me:

1. Open-Source examples of software that does the same or a similar thing, preferably in C
2. ANY literature on audio programming in C
3. Explanations on how the different formats are structured, any sources appreciated

Ps.: I apologise if some parts of the question can be easily googled, but I tried, and there wasn't anything that described this well in detail.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Not when you say chop out do you mean 'shorten' the sequence? That would totally ruin say stereo unless you synch them and potentially chop out frequencies outside the specified range. If not what frequency do you want instead of values in the range.

Comment: I want to completely remove any sound within the specified frequency. So if the specified frequency is 300-400hz, that range should be completely empty in the output file.
And yes, I know that the output would sound absolutely terrible, this is not about how it sounds though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) does a lot of audio slicing and dicing, and it's written in pure C. It's pretty big, though, and might be difficult to digest in one go.
2. "Audio programming" is a bit vague. But from the rest of your question, it sounds like you want to open an audio file from disk, apply some transformations to the audio, and write the data to a new file. (Other areas under the "audio programming" umbrella would include accessing platform-specific APIs to read from a microphone and write audio to an output device).
3. Broad topic again, but we'll start simple.

I suggest getting (or generating) a .WAV file to start with. WAV files are probably the simplest audio files to read and write manually. [Here is a page that describes what you need to know about the WAV format](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/).

Pulse code modulation (PCM) is the simplest audio format to work with since you don't need to worry about decompressing it first. [Here is a page (that I wrote) describing different PCM formats](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=PCM).

As for filtering and cutting different frequencies, I think what you're looking for would be [low-pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter), [high-pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter), or [band-pass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter) filters.

I hope that helps you get started. Ask more questions here on Stack Overflow as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should keep me busy for a while.
Are the filters harder to code for FLAC or MP3 files, than they are for WAV? Until now I was under the impression that WAV is more unintuitive to understand, but that page clarifies it very well! thanks!

Comment: Ps.: One part of the site you posted about WAV format is unclear to me. "8-bit samples are stored as unsigned bytes, ranging from 0 to 255. 16-bit samples are stored as 2's-complement signed integers, ranging from -32768 to 32767."
This is the only part that I identify as frequency, but there is no indication as to what frequency -32768 represents or which one 32767 does.
And I can't seem to find any information on how amplitude is represented either.
Probably it's just me, and it's somewhere in that text, so sorry if it is.
Much appreciated!

Comment: WAV as a container format is easier to take apart than FLAC or MP3. Plus, with those latter 2, you need to decompress the audio inside to get raw PCM. In WAV, you can start with raw PCM. As for 0..255 or -32768..32767, those are sample ranges, not frequencies. A PCM wave is comprised of a series of samples representing discrete wave amplitudes. For 16-bit samples at, say, 44100 Hz, there will be 44100 16-bit samples stored for every second of audio (twice that if it's stereo data).

Comment: Alright, so SampleRate is predefined as the article says - does that mean if it's at 44100, everything plays at a frequency of 44100hz, and the perceived pitch is sort of a "by-product" of the amplitudes? So for a 22050hz pure-tone, every second Sample would be silent?
(I guess I'll really have to broaden my understanding of computer-generated sound.)